# About objects in Java that have graphical representation and paint themselves

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple class to make buttons with.

I have, however, come to a serious problem, as I can't figure out how to properly implement painting those buttons.

I got a paint and update method inside the class itself, however, when I create an object of said class in another (the main) class, I have no way of actually running it, or interacting with it in any other way for that matter.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Buttons extends Canvas implements MouseListener {
    private Graphics g;
    private int xPos, yPos, width, hight;
    private Color DefultBG1;
    private boolean mouseOver, mousePressed;
    private Image im1, im2, im3, buff;
    private static ButtonListener btn;

public Buttons(ButtonListener btn, int x, int y, int width1, int hight1) {
    this.setBounds(x, y, x + width1, y + hight1);
    xPos=x;
    yPos=y;
    width=width1;
    hight=hight1;
    DefultBG1 = new Color(255, 255, 51);
    setBackground(DefultBG1);
    this.btn = btn;
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        if (buff == null) {
            buff = createImage(dim.width, dim.height);
            g = buff.getGraphics();
        }

    int bgwidth, bgheight = 0;

    if (mousePressed)
    {
        g.setColor(DefultBG1);
        g.fillRect(0,0,dim.width,dim.height);

        if (im3 != null)
        {
            bgwidth = im3.getWidth(this);
            bgheight = im3.getHeight(this);

            g.drawImage(im3,0,0,width,hight,this);
        }

    }
    else if (mouseOver)
    {
        g.setColor(DefultBG1);
        g.fillRect(0,0,dim.width,dim.height);
        if (im2 != null)
        {
            bgwidth = im2.getWidth(this);
            bgheight = im2.getHeight(this);

            g.drawImage(im2,0,0,width,hight,this);
        }


    }
    else
    {
        g.setColor(DefultBG1);
        g.fillRect(0,0,dim.width,dim.height);
        if (im1 != null)
        {
            bgwidth = im1.getWidth(this);
            bgheight = im1.getHeight(this);

            g.drawImage(im1,0,0,width,hight,this);
        }

    }
    g.drawImage(buff,0,0,this);

}

public void TestImage(int x){

    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        g.drawImage(im1,0,0,width,hight,this);
        break;
    case 2:
        g.drawImage(im2,0,0,width,hight,this);
        break;
    case 3:
        g.drawImage(im3,0,0,width,hight,this);
        break;
    }

}

public void ResizeBounds(int x, int y, int width1, int hight1) {
    this.setBounds(x, y, x + width1, y + hight1);
    xPos=x;
    yPos=y;
    width=width1;
    hight=hight1;
}

public void setImage(Image img, int state) {
    switch (state) {
    case 1:
        this.im1 = img;
        break;
    case 2:
        this.im2 = img;
        break;
    case 3:
        this.im3 = img;
        break;
    default:
        this.im1 = img;
    }

}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    mouseOver =true;
    setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    mouseOver =false;
    setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    mousePressed = true;

    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    btn.ButtonEvent(this);
    mousePressed = false;

    repaint();

}
```

Can anybody advice me of ways of making those buttons accessible from other classes?

Edit: And, of course, this is a general question too - how do you make objects of classes that have "paint" in them actually paint themselves in other classes (without copying all the code of said objects)?

Comment: To clarify: your objects paint themselves *when they are asked to paint*, by something calling the `paint` method. Usually, Swing will call the `paint` method of objects that are contained in a window.

Comment: Painting is done relative to the components top/left corner, that is, `0x0` is the components top/left corner...

Comment: @imminis  
That's my question - HOW do you ask them to be painted? Tried to do "object.paint()" in the main class, tried using the "TestImage" method I coded in there, both returned errors.  
Also, what is Swing?

Comment: @ronwizzle `repaint` is probably your best bet.  Swing is the Graphical User Interface library which replaced mainstream AWT some 15+ years ago...

Answer (score 1):

Painting is done from the context of the components top/left corner, that is, `0x0` is the components top/left position, this means you don't need to calculate the location of the component when you are painting.

In your current paint code, you are using the `xPos` and `yPos` position to do your painting, this means that the content is been painted at `xPos + xPos` x `yPos + yPos`...

Start by getting rid of the `xPos`, `yPos`, `width` and `hight` variables.  The width and height should be calculated by calling `getWidth` and `getHeight` WHEN you need them.

This `private static ButtonListener btn;` is a really bad idea, this means that it won't matter what you used when creating all the other instances of `Buttons`, only the last value of `btn` will ever be notified for ALL instances of `Buttons`

There are fews you can ask that a component be repainted, the best way, is to simply call `repaint`.

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in AWT

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked that one out, change the code a bit got rid of the listener, and while all looks good, I still can't make a button appear for some reason.

I'd post the new code in this reply but it's only 500 characters.

I try to call for B1.repaint(B1.getX(),B1.getY(),B1.getWidth(),B1.getHeight()); , and just for B1.repaint(); in the main class, both in init(), paint() and update(), yet it doesn't do anything. 

Where's my error?

Comment: Probably in you attempt to place it a pixel location manually. Your state information could also be wrong. Space some debug statements in your paint code and see what's going on...